# Stop empty strings at the database level with EF code first

Tags: entity-framework, null, ef-code-first, constraints

Consider the following POCO entity for Entity Framework Code First:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Which will generate the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Foo] (
    [Id]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]      NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Foo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Now, I understand that the default behavior of EF is to convert empty strings to null. So even if I explicitly feed it an empty string I will get a validation exception, *which is perfect*. The following code will throw a `DbEntityValidationException`:

```
var f = new Foo { Name = "" };
context.Foos.Add(f);
context.SaveChanges();
```

But, the problem is if I have an external application which accesses the database directly, I can perform the following query *and it succeeds*:

```
insert into dbo.Foo(Name)
values ('')
```

The best solution is arguably to not allow anyone to connect directly to the database and force them through a business layer. In reality however this may not always be possible. Especially if, say, I myself am importing external data via an SSIS package.

My best understanding says that applications should be set up to reject as much bad data *at the lowest level possible*. In this case this would mean the at database level. So if were creating the database the old fashioned way, I would add a constraint to check `(Name <> '')` and stop dirty data from ever being inserted in the first place.

Is there a way to get EF Code First to generate this constraint for me, or some other way to get it to enforce a non-empty-string (minimum length 1) at the database level - preferably using an attribute? Or is my only recourse to add the constraint manually in a migration?

Comment: what is "a migration" ? does it have any specific meaning in your context ?

Comment: @joedotnot I mean an EF Migration. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is `MinLength` attribute but it does not enforce the constraint on database level, you should add this constraint using migration I think.

```
public partial class test : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql("ALTER TABLE [dbo].[YOUR_TABLE] ADD CONSTRAINT " + 
            "[MinLengthConstraint] CHECK (DATALENGTH([your_column]) > 0)");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        Sql("ALTER TABLE [dbo].[YOUR_TABLE] DROP CONSTRAINT [MinLengthConstraint]");
    }
}
```

You can add sql code generators for EF to generate these codes for `MinLength` attribute, I'll give you a simplified hint here:

1. First mark properties with `MinLength`

   ```
   public class Test
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       [MinLength(1)]
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Add `MinLenghtAttribute` to conventions and provide the value, which is the `Length` :

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
       modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(
           new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<MinLengthAttribute, int>(
               "MinLength",
               (property, attributes) => attributes.Single().Length));
   }
   ```

   the generated code for migration will be:

   ```
   CreateTable(
       "dbo.Tests",
       c => new
           {
               Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
               Name = c.String(
                    annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
                    {
                        { 
                           "MinLength",
                            new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "1")
                        },
                    }),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
   ```
3. Override the `SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator` to use this convention in order to generate the `constraint` sql code:

   ```
   public class ExtendedSqlGenerator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
   {
       protected override void Generate(AddColumnOperation addColumnOperation)
       {
           base.Generate(addColumnOperation);
           AddConstraint(addColumnOperation.Column, addColumnOperation.Table);
       }

       protected override void Generate(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation)
       {
           base.Generate(createTableOperation);
           foreach (var col in createTableOperation.Columns)
                AddConstraint(col, createTableOperation.Name);
       }
       private void AddConstraint(ColumnModel column, string tableName)
       {
           AnnotationValues values;
           if (column.Annotations.TryGetValue("MinLength", out values))
           {
               var sql = string.Format("ALTER TABLE {0} ADD CONSTRAINT " +
                   "[MinLengthConstraint] CHECK (DATALENGTH([{1}]) >= {2})"
                   ,tableName, column.Name, values.NewValue);
               Generate(new SqlOperation(sql));
           }
      }
   }
   ```

   the code above contains generation for `AddColumn` and `CreateTable` operations you must add codes for `AlterColumn`, `DropTable` and `DropColumns` as well.
4. Register the new code generator:

   ```
   internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TestContext>
   {
       public Configuration()
       {
           AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
           SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new ExtendedSqlGenerator());
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: So that's how custom column annotations are supposed to work. This sounds pretty promising, and a whole lot better than having to manually add code to `Up()` and `Down()` - and worse yet remember I put it there.